# Object is possibly 'undefined' even after undefined was added to reducer interface

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error that breaks my application:

```
index.js:1 /Users/luiscortes/Projects/ministryjs/src/components/code-cell.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/luiscortes/Projects/ministryjs/src/components/code-cell.tsx(15,46):
Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532

    13 | const CodeCell: React.FC<CodeCellProps> = ({ cell }) => {
    14 |   const { updateCell, createBundle } = useActions();
  > 15 |   const bundle = useTypedSelector((state) => state.bundles[cell.id]);
       |                                              ^
    16 | 
    17 |   useEffect(() => {
    18 |     const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
```

I thought the solution would be to add or undefined inside my `bundlesReducer.ts` file like so:

```
import produce from "immer";
import { ActionType } from "../action-type";
import { Action } from "../actions";

interface BundlesState {
  [key: string]:
    | {
        loading: boolean;
        code: string;
        err: string;
      }
    | undefined;
}

const initialState: BundlesState = {};

const reducer = produce(
  (state: BundlesState = initialState, action: Action): BundlesState => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionType.BUNDLE_START:
        state[action.payload.cellId] = {
          loading: true,
          code: "",
          err: "",
        };
        return state;
      case ActionType.BUNDLE_COMPLETE:
        state[action.payload.cellId] = {
          loading: false,
          code: action.payload.bundle.code,
          err: action.payload.bundle.err,
        };
        return state;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
);

export default reducer;
```

Yet, the error still persists. What other fix am I missing? I tried writing a type guard, but that did not make the error go away.

I am obtaining that `bundles` from `combineReducers()` here:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import cellsReducer from "./cellReducers";
import bundlesReducer from "./bundlesReducer";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  cells: cellsReducer,
  bundles: bundlesReducer,
});

export default reducers;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;
```

Adding an optional with a question mark at the end of `state.bundles` just creates a problem where there is the expectation of a colon at the end.

This is my `use-type-selector.ts` file:

```
import { useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../state";

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Comment: `(state.bundles ?? {})[cell.id]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return `produce` from your reducer and `immer` will be able to infer the types

```
const bundlesReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
    }
  })
```

After looking around it seems you can also give `produce` the initial state value and it will be typed as expected

```
const bundlesReducer = produce((state, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  }
}, initialState);
```

Comment: your solution resolved it. I guess I improperly used `produce()`. I am now getting a new type of error and still a broken app, but it resolved this one. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Doesn't look like a misuse of the function, if you give it the initial state as a second argument it will be typed as expected, so that's better than wrapping the reducers I think.

Comment: I came to that solution as you were writing this. All I needed to do was add a second argument of `initialState`. I came to this solution by looking at my other reducer and realizing I had did the same thing there, its just I never got an error for that one so I was unable to make the connection right away.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the method signature of `useTypedSelector`? Apparently `state` inside the callback function can be `undefined`.

When changing the `reducer` you change the setting-side of the store while you should have changed the getting-side of the store i.e. the selector.